# jQuery: FadeIn a selected value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selected box with 5 values. I'm trying to fadeIn inputs of what is selected in the box. For example: If input1 is selected, fade in input1 on click.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function() {
               if($("#selectbox").value == 'Input1') {
            $(".input1").show();
        } else if($("#selectbox").value == 'Input2') {
            $(".input2").show();
        } else if($("#selectbox").value == 'Input3') {
            $(".input3").show();
        } else if($("#selectbox").value == 'Input4') {
            $(".input4").show();
        } else if($("#selectbox").value == 'Input5') {
            $(".input5").show();
        }
    }
});
```

And here is a NOT working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzMHJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have two errors and that's why its not working.

1. <strike>`$("#selectbox").value`</strike> should be  `$("#selectbox").val()`
2. you have not closed your click event with `);`

Also its much better to use switch case in this example.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/Zn2yy/

**Update** (based on Nick Cravers comment)

For this particular scenario you could simplify code a lot like this.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BWacA/

Comment: I'd argue for a (to me at least) much simpler using of the value as the selector, e.g. `$("."+$("#selectbox").val().toLowerCase()).show();`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BWacA/

Comment: Just as a comment:  From a user standpoint, depending on the implementation I bet I would rather have the function fire on the onChange of the select rather than make me select and click again.

Comment: @mikeY. The reason i did this is because the select box's will be in settings where you will be choosing some default values and the values will be saved so on refresh it will check if that is selected, show this etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code that is causing it to fail.

First, replace `.value` with the jQuery function `val()`.

Second, add `);` to the second to last `}` at the end.

Here is working refactored code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var show = "." + $("#selectbox").val().toLowerCase();
        $(show).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this example because its less code, but how can you hide the rest inputs after you press the button few times? $(input).hide(); won't work.